# can sybase replication be used to synchronize sybase and mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, replication, sybase, rdbms

I see that mysql replication can synchronize from sybase, but can sybase replication server write to and read from sybase?
I'm trying to figure out a migration path of a big old legacy sybase system lots of little applications to mysql and figure I can move the newer apps sooner than the older ones so I want to be able to use both and have sybase replication do the synchronizing.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Sybase replication server only works between Sybase instances.

Golden Gate software has an excellent solution for real time inter-database replication.  You can set it up to bi-replicate, so that changes on each side are propagated.

http://www.goldengate.com

Answer (score 1):

Sybase replication server can replicate between Sybase, MS SQL, Oracle and DB2. It doesn't look like it can do MYSQL.

http://www.sybase.com/products/businesscontinuity/replicationserver/heterogeneousreplication

Answer (score 0):

Sybase Replicaton Server can replicate between Sybase and MySQL.
You just need to use the MSSS function class when installing Replication Server.